# Sharing a struct with a pointer between two processes using `shm_open()`

Tags: c, arrays, struct, posix, shared-memory

I have the following struct,

```
typedef struct arrays {
    int *array;
    int max;
    int min;
} array;
```

Where `*array` points to an dynamically allocated array, `max` and `min` holds the maximum and minimum numbers in the array.

I need to share an instance (can I use the word 'instance' in C?) of this struct between two processes, am I supposed to use `shm_open()` first for allocating the array pointed by `*array` and second for allocating the struct itself, or is there a better way achieving the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this.

1. Use **shm_open** in each process to get a *file descriptor*. You must pass shm_open the same *name* in each process. The name is what distinguishes the shared memory region from other shared memory regions. The name must begin with a slash: `"/somename"`.
2. Use the file descriptor obtained in step 1 to call **mmap**.
3. The address returned from `mmap` is your shared memory address. It is random and different in each process.
4. Because of 3, you cannot use pointers inside a shared memory region. You need to either use integer offsets from the start of the shared memory, or do away with indirection altogether. For instance, treat the entire shared memory region as an integer array. The first two cells hold `min` and `max` and the actual numbers start after that.
5. `mmap` will return usable memory, you don't need to allocate any buffers either statically or with `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's *better* but you can do it with only a single allocation: Allocate one large buffer to include both the structure *and* the array, then make `array` point to the buffer + the size of the structure.

Comment: I like this idea, how do I make sure that everything points to what it should? I understand how to make `*array` point to after the struct but I don't understand how can I make `max` and `min` functional.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the first asnwer is like when you tell the doctor "It hurts when I do this" and the doctor says "then dont DO that!"

Assuming you're intent on this, remember that `shm_open` makes a block of memory avaiailable for sharing: if you have a pointer to malloc'd memory in the memory you share, it will be a pointer to some random address in the heap as far as the other process is concerned.  You need to allocate the whole buffer, the whole chunk of memory, and then share that.

**Update**

Per the question below, if you want to allocate the buffer *during runtime* then the canonical way would be:

```
#define HOWBIGISMYBUFFER (3*GAZILLION)
char * buf;
if((buf = malloc(HOWBIGISMYBUFFER)) == 0){
    /* make splodey noises and terminate */
}
/* now you have your buffer */
```

where, of course `GAZILLION` is defined elsewhere.  That said, however, *you don't want to do that*.  What you're trying to achieve is a static block of memory that can be shared, and allocating it on the heap exposes you to all sorts of very hard to track bugs. (Consider, eg, you allocate the memory in program A, share it to program B, and program B then corrupts program A's heap by a buffer overflow.  Or consider, what if program B keeps running after program A crashes?)

What you want to do instead is create a *static* buffer.  The easiest way is by making a `.h` file:

```
/* my_buffer.h */
char bfr[HOWBIGISMYBUFFER];
```

and then including that anywhere you want to share the memory.  What *I* would do instead is write a module:

```
/* my_buffer.c */
char bfr[HOWBIGISMYBUFFER];

char * init(){ /* do your shm_open here and returna pointer to bfr */ }
```

Comment: Do you mean something like nested `shm_open`s? I was thinking about it but it ruins readability of the code.

Comment: no.  Look ay the function prototype: it takes a const char *. It want you to allocate all the space you're going to use.

Comment: Ues, although I think there's an underlying point of understanding you need. shm_open takes a *block of memory*, a sequential collection of addresses, and gives it a OS identifier that lets another program map the same chunk of memory.  What you really want is a an array of bytes, a fixed chunk of memory.

Comment: Reading and thinking about it for the whole day I have successfully implemented your suggestion in C.

Comment: Yay!  You have also learned something a little deeper about how the damn computer actually works.  This will serve you well.

Comment: I actually knew what's supposed to happen in theory, but given a little guidance and an explanation from a different POV helped me nailing it!

Comment: @CharlieMartin can you please show an example of how to allocate the whole buffer, when allocating an array (or any other memory) during runtime?

Comment: This is totally incorrect. Please at least read the entitre man page on shm_open before giving advice. The pointer you seem to mistake for a shareable memory address in fact must point to a *name*. Downvoted and flagged.

Comment: It was actually a very good answer before he added the example that can mislead people. `shm_open` alone will return a file descriptor which should later be used by `mmap` to map it to a virtual address in the process's virtual address space.

Comment: Yeha, I just confounded shm_open and mmap itself.  That's what happens when you been doing this programming stuff for 50 years.